# JAVA Grpc Client

Tags: grpc-java

I am trying to consumer a GRPC service from a spring java client.  All of the examples I am finding online are generating a java class from something similar to below.  The proto I am using does not have this defined.  Is there a way to manually build a grpc java client without using the maven plugin?  If so how would I do it?

```
service HelloService {
    rpc hello(HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse);
}
```

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gRPC is using code gen via `protobuf-maven-plugin` if you are using maven. Proto should have service definition (`HelloService` in your example) and message definitions (`HelloRequest`, `HelloResponse`).

For your own service, you should define service(s). I encourage you to look at grpc tutorial which explains all the steps to create a gRPC service from scratch.

grpc toturial: https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/java/

if you want to avoid using maven plugin, you can write your own code that the plugin generates for you. so it is technically possible, but no reason to do it.